# Cannot implicity convert type Generic List error MVC WCF

Tags: wcf, model-view-controller

I'm working with MVC and WCF Service.My MVC Project and WCF Service in same solution.I have same customer classes in mvc project and wcf service project.
I write a method in service return `List<Customer>` and I want to call this method in mvc project but I have an error like "Cannot implicity convert type `<x.Customer>` to `<y.Customer>` ".

Anyway I change service reference configuration like Generic.List but I have same error. How can I fix the problem?

```
public class ReportService : IReportService
{
    protected static List<Customer> Customers;
    public List<Customer> GetReport(string Name,string Surname,string Address,string Phone) {
        //NHibernate üzerinden select
        Customers = new List<Customer>();

        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var results = from c in session.Query<Customer>()
                              select c;
                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    Customer customer = new Customer
                    {
                        CustomerId = result.CustomerId,
                        Name = result.Name,
                        Surname = result.Surname,
                        Address = result.Address,
                        Phone = result.Phone
                    };

                    Customers.Add(customer);
                }

                if (Customers.Count>0)
                {
                    return Customers;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

MVC code:

```
ServiceReport.ReportServiceClient service = new ServiceReport.ReportServiceClient();

List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
list = service.GetReport(Name, Surname, Address, Phone);
```

Comment: It sounds like you have two `Customer` types. That's the problem - and likely to be a cause of confusion as well. I would suggest getting rid of one of those types, or *at least* renaming one of them - at which point the error will be clearer. (I'd also not create an empty list pointlessly - just use `List<Customer> list = service.GetReport(...);`. I'd also rename your parameters and variables to follow .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: (Oh, and I'd use LINQ more thoroughly too - put all your transformation code into the `select` clause... your code can be simplified very significantly. Also, it's generally friendlier to callers to return an empty list rather than a null reference. They can still easily check for that if they need to, but they don't *have* to if they just want to find the count or iterate over it...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I change Customer class name like CustomerType.cs in WCF project but I have a same error.

Comment: Well you can't just change the filename - you need to change the class itself... and if that's being generated for you, I would leave *that* class alone and change the other one - not that we know where the other one comes from yet...

Comment: @JonSkeet I delete this class in WCF Project and I create new class like CustomerTypes.cs and I build wcf project and update service referance in MVC project but I have same error. I guess it is about two projects in same solution?

Comment: No, not really. If you have the *exact* same error, with the same type name (`x.Customer` and `y.Customer`) then your new class presumably isn't being used...

Comment: @JonSkeet this error like (x.CustomerTypes and y.Customer) this is annoying:(

Comment: Ah, so you *don't* get the same error. You get a different error. So presumably your ReportService is now creating a `List<CustomerType>`, and no, you can't assign that to a variable of type `List<Customer>`. You'll either need to get down to one single, shared type - or convert between `CustomerType` and `Customer`.

Comment: @JonSkeet First of all Thanks for answers. How can I sharedtype for two project in same solution?

Comment: Well presumably your MVC code already refers to your WCF code, so just use CustomerType everywhere...

Comment: @JonSkeet I user CustomerType everywhere but I have this error  method add_PropertyChanged should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow really isn't meant to be an interactive debugging tool. If you've now got an entirely different error, do an appropriate amount of research to fix it yourself, and ask a new question if you absolutely have to. I would suggest deleting this question though.